# How can I connect a Webcam, which has a mic, to headphones -- before the signal enters my laptop -- to avoid time-delay?

Tags: usb, audio, webcam, microphone

I am using the Audacity music recording software.  Doing multitracking, one needs to wear headphones while playing an instrument.  The sound of the instrument itself goes into the headphones, along with prior recorded tracks.  But if I simply plug headphones into the laptop, there is a delay, like an echo.  I need to be able to hear the mic'ed signal from the mic, before it enters the computer.  If I were using a conventional -- e.g., condensor-- mic with an XLR jack, I could plug it into a USB audio interface, wich has a headphone plug.  But the Logitech doesn't have any plugs, and I can't plug it into a USB audio interface.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to completely eliminate the latency unless you use an external audio interface into which you plug input source, eg mic/keyboard/guitar & also output destination, eg headphones/speakers.

The internal routing on the interface will then allow you to route the mic signal straight back to the headphones without first having to go through the computer. It can mix this with the existing recording being played back from the computer.

This, of course, all requires that you have mic/headphones compatible with the interface - this will preclude USB devices.